# Unable to Run the Fast API Application deployed in Docker Container

Tags: docker, deployment, fastapi

I have create a Docker Image based on the following DockerFile

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7
COPY . /usr/app/
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /usr/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["uvicorn", "app_Testing_Praveen:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

following the documentation available at

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/

After running the command

```
docker run -p 80:80 image_name
```

My docker image is running but giving the address as 0.0.0.0:80

But I am not able to find the absolute link to open the application. I know, due to virtualization there will be different external IP address for docker.

I found that IP on my docker network interface as "docker subnet mask" but that value is also not opening the applicatiln on browser.

My docker version is Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88 and I am running this on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reach your services inside Docker containers, via the IP of the host machine

So you either access your service by `http://localhost:80` or, from another machine, with `http://<docker_host_ip>:80`.

Comment: Thank you very much.. http://localhost:80 . It worked

Comment: No problem! :) Don’t forget to mark it as the answer to the question

Comment: docker_host_ip the IP of the calling container or the IP of the target container?